# Facebook share button re sizes by itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, share-button

my Facebook share button worked perfectly until a few days ago when it started re sizing itself and refusing to open, any clues as to what is causing this?\

here's my js script for the pop-up window

```
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width=' + winWidth + ',height=' + winHeight);
}
```

here's the link

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://dundaah.com/docs/tue.html', 'Fb Share', 'Facebook share popup', 'http://goo.gl/dS52U', 520, 350)" class="button">Share</a>
```

if this looks familiar it's cause I got it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/eyxtj/)

Comment: Its working on my chrome browser

Comment: Must be a browser issue. Please check on other browsers.

Comment: What browser are you using? Did you try in a different browser?